# reFind corrupted SSD

Tags: macos, efi

I was using a Macbook Pro 2015 with a 20 GB partition for Linux and rest Mac OS X.

I had a security update for MacOS Sierra and did that. After that my reFind boot loader stopped showing up.

Then I tried recovering my 19 GB by going to disk utilities but I got an error. I went ahead with my work. Next day I turned on my machine and I got a reFind window(no Mac OS). I went to recovery(Cmd+R) and then erased my disk.

I tried installing MacOS again by using Internet Recovery tools and external bootable drive.

Internet recovery keeps on breaking and external bootable keeps giving me this error:-

`The operation couldn't be completed (com.apple.osinstallersetup.LinkFileDownload error 3.)`

Please see my disk details below and if there is a way I can fix this.

Details:-

General Info

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS MacOsX                  250.7 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *32.0 GB    disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Install macOS Sierra    31.7 GB    disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +5.9 GB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS OS X Install ESD        5.5 GB     disk3s2

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk4
   1:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        2.0 GB     disk4s1

/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +5.2 MB     disk5

/dev/disk6 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk6

/dev/disk7 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk7

/dev/disk8 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk8

/dev/disk9 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk9

/dev/disk10 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk10

/dev/disk11 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk11

/dev/disk12 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk12

/dev/disk13 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk13

/dev/disk14 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk14

/dev/disk15 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk15

/dev/disk16 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk16

/dev/disk17 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk17

/dev/disk18 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk18

/dev/disk19 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk19

/dev/disk20 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk20
```

Disk Details:-

```
-bash-3.2# gpt -r show /dev/disk0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  489562928      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  489972568     262151         
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
-bash-3.2#
```

Comment: What does "After that my reFind boot loader stopped showing up." mean? This says what the computer did not do, but I need to know what  did the computer do? Next, you state you are using the disk utilities. So, am I to assume the computer booted to the disk utilities instead of rEFInd?

Comment: And, what are the disk utilities? Is this the command `disktuil`? Or perhaps this is 'gpt', 'fdisk', 'gdisk', etc....  Maybe, the Disk Utility application, but this would require first booting to a macOS, macOS recovery, internet macOS recovery, a USB macOS installer, another computer via Target Disk mode, an external disk with macOS installer or one of many other ways to get an OS.

Comment: The reFind loader stopped showing up means that the OS straight away started booting from MacOS, with no prompt being shown that was shown initially, to choose from MacOS or Linux.

Comment: When my computer stopped showing MacOS, I used Cmd+R that straight away went to Internet Recovery Tool. I then erased my drive with JHFS type and then started downloading chunks which kept failing.

Comment: The commands are used in the recovery mode Terminal window.Yes the command is `diskutil` . The recovery mode was achieved using an external bootable USB. I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 1):

From your question and comments, this is how I chronologically pieced together events.

> Note: Apple macOS refers to the volume, where the file the EFI firmware is suppose to load resides, as the startup disk. In the case of a BIOS boot (on models the can BIOS boot), the firmware always executes software on the Master Boot Record (MBR) provided the drive has a valid hybrid partitioning scheme.

1. A security update for macOS Sierra was installed. The default startup disk was changed to the volume where macOS resides.
2. The `diskutil` command failed to merge all or part of the space occupied by Linux back to the partition where macOS is installed.
3. On startup, the Mac was unable to boot to the default startup disk (the macOS volume). This caused the firmware to search for any software that may be bootable. This resulted in a boot of rEFInd.
4. The Mac was rebooted to macOS Recovery over the Internet. The `diskutil` command, given below, was used to erase the entire internal drive. An attempt to install macOS on an external drive lead to failure.

   ```
   diskutil  eraseDisk  JHFS+  MacOsX  GPT  disk0
   ```

There are may ways the default startup disk can be changed from rEFInd. Below is a list some of the possible ways.

- From the firmware Startup Manager
- From macOS System Preferences
- From the Windows Control Panel (Requires Boot Camp)
- From the Windows System Tray (Requires Boot Camp)
- By reseting the NVRAM (PRAM)
- By executing the `bless` command
- By installing or reinstalling macOS (OS X)
- By the installation of a software update.

The last item, in this list, caused rEFInd to initially disappear at startup. Steps 2 through 4 were not only unnecessary, but lead to the corruption.

You asked "Please see my disk details below and if there is a way I can fix this?" Well, there is nothing to fix. Evidently, you erased everything. At this point, just reinstall macOS.

Comment: I tried re-installing macOS. I keep on getting the error I mentioned above. I used the same external USB to install MacOS on an external Hard Disk and I am able to use that. However my internal SSD keeps on giving me the error ,using the same external USB.

Comment: Is there any other good software that can repair my disk? Because both the first Aid and the apple diagnostics by running D key while startup report no errors. Also while booting up from external hard disk, my internal SSD shows up in Finder.

Comment: And why do you say steps 2 through 4 were un-necessary? Before when I downloaded MacOS High Sierra update I could not install it and the installer gave me an error, "Cannot install on this disk", so I figured I will have to delete my Linux partition. And I took this opportunity to clean install MacOS on my internal SSD

Comment: No where in your question have you mentioned the installation of the update failed. The main difficulty in answering your question is not knowing what actually happened. You seem to only post what you what to without knowing if something you left out is important.

Comment: I posted in my answer based on what I read from your question and comments. I believe what you actually did differs somewhat. Can you read my answer and confirm these were the steps taken?

Comment: I believed steps 2 through 4 were unnecessary because all you needed to do is set the default startup disk back to rEFInd. The procedure to do this depends on how rEFInd was installed.

Comment: Yes the steps are correct. However as for step 4, I first erased the internal SSD using Disk Utility, then tried installing MacOS over the internet. That kept failing. Then made an external bootable USB. Tried installing with that. It failed with the error mentioned above.

Comment: Then I used the terminal command to erase the SSD. Again tried same error. Afterwards I used the same bootable to install MacOS on an external 1TB Hard Disk and that works fine on the device.

Comment: You could try running the command `sudo fsck_hfs -S /dev/disk0s2` and see if any bad blocks are returned. This command will probably take a long time to  finish. You should set your Mac to not sleep.

Comment: `Got a non I/O error reading disk at offset 47679799296:  Device not configured` This is the output that I got. What does this mean?

Comment: The error occured while executing the function `pread`. The documentation for `pread` states the reason for the error was either " An action is requested of a device that does not  exist.." or "A requested action cannot be performed by the device.". Since the `fsck_hfs` command read approximately 93124608 sectors before the error occurred, I believe the error to be "An action is requested of a device that does not  exist.." In other words, you SSD disappeared while executing `fsck_hfs`. This would indicate failure of the logic board, cable or SSD.

Comment: If you are curious and want to read the code for yourself, then search for `non I/O` in the code given [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/hfs/hfs-366.70.1/fsck_hfs/fsck_hfs.c). This is the main block of code for the command `fsck_hfs`. This one file is part of [macOS 10.12.6 Source](https://opensource.apple.com/release/macos-10126.html).

Comment: Yes you are right. My SSD disappears randomly. I will get my device repaired. Thanks for all the help. :)